# Adding a constant to each cell before taking PRODUCT, without a helper column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to compute `=(A1+1)*(A2+1)*...*(A100+1)`. I could make a helper column with each value in *A* incremented, and then take `=PRODUCT(B1:B100)`. Can I do this in one step without a helper column?

My guess, `=PRODUCT((A1:A100)+1)` is syntactically valid but I believe it really just returns `=A1+1`.

It's possible one could use `SEQUENCE()` as in `=PRODUCT(A1:A100 + SEQUENCE(1,100)/SEQUENCE(1,100))` but this is (a) horrible and (b) only available in Office 365.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add; then multiply:

```
=PRODUCT(A1:A100+1)
```

*In some earlier versions of Excel, you may need to "confirm" this **array-formula** it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar*